# ElasticSearch: Trying to get City, State within distance to latitude/longitude and sort by distance from origin

Tags: elasticsearch, geocoding

What I have is a dataset that has IP Ranges and has city, state, zipcode, latitude, longitude for each IP Range.

What I want to get out is the city, state values that are closest to a given lat/lon. So, if this were SQL I'd do a group by city, state. How do I do this in ElasticSearch? I've been trying to use facets, but I'm either getting ALL city,state values in the database (via term facet) or I end up getting no city,state values.

Note that I do have a separately indexed field that contains city and state in a single indexed, not_analyzed field.

I'm also unsure where to do the GeoDistance check. I've tried using a Query, a Filter, and filter facet. I'm basically at a loss right now. Not sure if I've been staring at it too long or what.

EDIT: So, I've figured this out using an aggregation (added in 1.0) but I want to expose a minimum distance so that I can sort these aggregation buckets by the minimum geodistance for each bucket. So, let's say I have a bucket that contains all documents for NEW YORK, NEW YORK and I have another bucket that contains all documents for ALBANY, NEW YORK. Now, I want to be able to access the minimum geodistance for each bucket so that I know if Albany or New York City is closer to my origin point.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this page has everything you need:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/geo-location-and-search/

If there's anything you need after reading that feel free to ask ;)

Comment: Nope, because I need the output of closest points, grouped by city,region name, with the groups ordered by the minimum distance of any point in that group. All that explains is what I already know: that those can all be done separately but not together.

I thought the aggregations api would be the answer, but it appears not yet.